# I'm never ever able to login to my console (Alt + Ctrl + F1)

Tags: login, root, console

I'm not able to login to my console from a long time. Facing this issue with pc and my laptop too. I thought this could be my Keyboard layout problem because my keyboard is 13 years old yeah even older than Ubuntu but I'm facing this in my laptop too and on Virtual Box too. I tried different distributions like Opensuse, Elementary, Xubuntu, Manjaro, Linux Mint same issue every where.

What I had tried till now :

1. Using number pad below the Function keys no solution
2. Using different password like telephone number or big password with lower and uppercase
3. Keyboard layout is proper everything types perfectly

I'm able to login to my Terminal with following commands.

```
sudo -i
sudo login
```

Answer (score 0):

so if you cant login as root @ console:

Login the "sudo way":

```
sudo -i
```

Change the password:

```
passwd
```

Use a password which dont contains layout-depending chars...